# What is the answer

Tags: riddle

> To start the beginning
>
> of a?
>
> To be simplified
>
> by a mere?
>
> A way to represent me
>
> is a laugh replaced by you.
>
> But all these clues are irrelevant
>
> I have already given you the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is :

> What (credit to [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi), I'm just addressing the clues)

To start the beginning

of a?

> If you let the ? represent the word question, the sentence says "To start the beginning of a question" which the word "what" often does.

To be simplified

by a mere?

> In text chat, "?" can mean the same thing as asking "what?"

A way to represent me

is a laugh replaced by you.

> If you replace "ha" (a laugh) with "u" (you), then you have phonetically the same word, and "[wut](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/045/n725075089_288918_2774.jpg)" is sometimes used instead of "what" on the internet.

I have already given you the answer

> The title of the riddle supplies the answer: "What is the answer".