# The answer to this riddle is a number

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

I made this up myself a while back, just thought I'd share:

> The key to this riddle is only for you
>   Below are instructions, above this the clue
>   First strike the one near the head of a year
>   Then remove he who begins a cheer
>   Next take away the end of a tunnel
>   Then let us go to solve this puzzle
>   What you first took you must now take again
>   With three you are left, but fret not dear friend
>   Fattest to front and thinnest to rear
>   Add in two "eyes" and all becomes clear

Like the title says (I'm not very good with titles), you're looking for a number here.

Edited to add a hint:

> As you can tell from the title, I tend to be very literal with my words.

Comment: Could we have a hint? :)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, this was only asked an hour ago.  Give people some time to try to solve it!  :)

Comment: Alright, pulling my hair, but alright.

Comment: I suppose I could post a hint in spoiler format so people can choose not to look at it, but to be honest I'll need time to come up with a good one.

Comment: No hard rule on it but people usually people give it at least a day before posting hints.

Comment: I think I know the answer, but not where to start in order to get there...

Comment: @Alconja: I'd love to know how you got to the answer you think you know then!

Comment: I have serveral possible solutions on my mind, but, as Alconja said, it seems unclear where to start from, which prevents me from validating any of my guesses.

Comment: 14 upvotes, but no answer ? hmmm ...

Comment: Man. How do you guys get to the point of having answers in mind with no starting point?? I'm super curious.

Comment: @Xenocacia For we are smart :)

Comment: @Xenocacia - don't want to spoil it if I am right (and that's obviously a big if, it's entirely possible I'm way off), but I'll report back after it's solved (or if I find a definite solution)... But to put it cryptically, my theoretical solution definitely points at your hint/title...

Comment: Hello @Xanocacia, can I add this puzzle to my website? I will post it under your nickname there. Cheers.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan: hey there, sure! I took a quick look at your website; looks great! I'm flattered that you asked. :)

Comment: I thought it might be '4', because it said 'above this is the clue', and directly above it is the word 'for'.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Answer:

> 18, or XVIII in Roman Numerals

Rationale:

The key to this riddle is only for you

> Exclusive

Below are instructions, above this the clue

First strike the one near the head of a year

> Take away an "e"

Then remove he who begins a cheer

> Take away a "c"

Next take away the end of a tunnel

> Take away an "l"

Then let us go to solve this puzzle

> Take away a "u" and an "s"

What you first took you must now take again

> Take away another "e"

With three you are left, but fret not dear friend
Fattest to front and thinnest to rear

> Arrange the remaining letters, XIV, in order of size - XVI

Add in two "eyes" and all becomes clear

> Add two further "I"s to get XVIII

Comment: Oh, very nice! Well done, I think you've got it :-)

Comment: Excellent first answer, could be correct as well...

Comment: And welcome to Puzzling, of course :-)

Comment: Ah, I thought it was *exclusive* but didn't think of Roman numbers. This must be it

Comment: Congratulations!! This is correct, well done! I hope you guys had fun solving this and do let me know how I can improve future puzzles.

Comment: Cool! If it's of interest to you, I worked backwards from the Roman Numerals idea, and wrote down the set of {M, C, L, X, V, I} along with all the letters that got subtracted out. "Exclusive" was the very last thing I figured out.

Comment: @StevenEccles: that IS interesting; never thought it could possibly be solved in that relatively brute-force method.

Comment: I was not aware of this convention that that these clues were presumed to be referring to individual letters.  I looked up "head of a year" and discovered it's a British term for a particular type of school teacher.  At that point I assumed I wouldn't get this without being British and I gave up!

Comment: I don't get why "2 eyes" equals 2 times I, can you explain pls?

Comment: I don't get the part, 'take u and s'

Comment: let us go - let "us" go - let "u" and "s" go from the key word

Comment: @MarioGarcia in lots of Anglophone accents "eye" and "I" are homophones i.e. they sound identical.

Comment: @StevenEccles aah yeah, now _eye_ got it :D Thanks

Answer (score 32):

Ok, since others are posting partial answers, I'll throw my theory into the ring...

If the thing that is "only for you" is:

> **Delegate** (because a delegate is *my* representative??)

Then we follow the instructions thusly:

*First strike the one near the head of a year*

> Remove the "**e**" from the end (if the "*y*" is the head of "year", the "*e*" is *near* the head), to give **delegat**

*Then remove he who begins a cheer*

> Remove the "**a**", since it begins "**a** cheer", to give **delegt**

*Next take away the end of a tunnel*

> Remove "**el**" (end of "a tunn**el**"), to get **degt**

*What you first took you must now take again*

> Remove another "*e*" to get **dgt**

*With three you are left, but fret not dear friend / Fattest to front and thinnest to rear*

> We now have three letters left, as it says. **D** is a fat looking letter, so it goes at the front, and **T** goes at the end since it's the thinnest (but the fact that they already are in that position, and that "delegate" is a bit if a stretch for "only for you" makes me think this answer is at least partially wrong...)

*Add in two "eyes" and all becomes clear*

> Add two "**i**"s, and we get a final solution of **DIGIT**. Given that a digit is indeed a number, we satisfy the title/hint nicely.

Comment: Very interesting take! Alphabetical order is also respected in your Fattest to Thinnest part, don't know what it means though.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the existing answers :

> i guess **42**

Because

> Beastly Gerbil's 'for ou o' means we should replace o by ou in 'for' making 'four', then the two eyes would be 1 and 1 (shaped like the letter i). so four and 2 = **42**. It seems to be the answer to a lot of questions anyway !

Comment: That is my guess as well! Sadly it is unexplainable, we have to skip clues/jump to answers to get there.

Comment: @Joe Derksen: I, too, am a great fan of Douglas Adams, but that would be too much of a leap. :)

Answer (score 5):

Well I'm getting somewhere but can't put it all together

Okay so far I have found

> The key to this puzzle is only for you, the fact that it says he is very literal with his words means that the key is 'Only for you'

Then the riddle tells us we have some instructions:

First strike the one near the head of a year

> We have to take away 'y'

Then remove he who begins a cheer

> Remove 'c' or 'ch'?

Next take away the end of a tunnel

> Remove 'nel'

Then let us go to solve this puzzle

> So we have all we need

What you first took you must now take again

> Take another 'y'

With three you are left, but fret not dear

Fattest to front and thinnest to rear

> Move word with most letters to front, least to back

Add in two "eyes" and all becomes clear

> Add in two 'i's somewhere

So

> We apply the instructions on the key

So

> 'only for you' --> 'onl for you'
> 'onl for you' --> ???? (No c on this?)
> ???! --> 'o for you' (No 'nel' only 'nl')
> 'o for you' --> 'o for ou'
> 'o for ou' --> 'for ou o'
> 'for ou o' --> ???? (Have to add two 'i's)

My best guess is

> Four

Because

> The furthest I got 'for ou o' suggests 'ou' needs to replace 'o' so we have 'four'

Another possible answer:

> a number

May be other clues but

> The answer to this riddle is 'a number'

Answer (score 4):

I am unsure if I am on the right track, but so far I understand this much:

The key to this riddle is only for you

> The key is the phrase "only for you"

Below are instructions, above this the clue

> Telling us the important phrase to start with

First strike the one near the head of a year

> Remove a 'y' from the phrase, results in "onl for you"

Then remove he who begins a cheer

> This is where I am stuck, logically I would remove 'c' since 'c' begins a "cheer" but there is no 'c' in the phrase

Next take away the end of a tunnel

> End of a tunnel is 'l'. Removing that leaves us with "on for you"

Then let us go to solve this puzzle

> Not sure if this line is important or just to rhyme with tunnel

What you first took you must now take again

> The first character we removed was 'y', removing it again leaves "on for ou"

With three you are left, but fret not dear friend

> We're left with 3 words

Fattest to front and thinnest to rear

> Again, I am unsure at this line, possibly sort according to number of letters? But "on" and "ou" contain 2 letters each.

Add in two "eyes" and all becomes clear

> Adding 'i' to 2 positions should spell out a number.

This is my reasoning so far, trying to figure out the rest.

**Edit**, interesting observation by M Oehm

> "Striking" the one near the head of a year could refer to the 'l' in "only" as it is 'near' the 'y' (head of a year). Turning it into "onty". However, that makes the "tunnel" hint harder as there is no more 'l' to remove.

About the hint:

> Seeing as how he focuses on the title and his literal word meaning so much, imagine the answer turns out to be "**a number**". The answer is in the title! Fits the hint.

Comment: I'm in the same place you are here

Comment: Nice tries all round, I don't know how to (or if) I should help shed light at this early stage so I'm going to just hang back and see how it goes. :)

Comment: @humn Interesting thinking, but then I can't remove those from our main phrase. Also check out my final hint. What a thought!

Comment: Hah, related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/39006/what-is-the-answer  and  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23398/what-is-the-title-to-this-question

Comment: @humn A very interesting question there, had me laughing :)

Comment: It says to strike the one _near_ the head of a year, which to me suggests not to remove the y, but one of the adjacent letters. (And maybe we don't have to remove a letter, but must "strike" through the l in only to get a t.)

Comment: A lot of people have solid, logical ideas, but somehow all the puzzle pieces don't seem to fit together!

Comment: My answer is NOT just the phrase "a number": that would be too cruel and misleading!

Comment: "Then let us go to solve this puzzle", I read that as remove all the letter 'u'. (Let u's go to solve this puzzle). Not sure if that helps though :)

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is:

> **Zero**.

The key to this riddle is only for you

> The key is said to be "only".

Below are instructions, above this the clue

> Quite literal.

First strike the one near the head of a year

> Take away the one near "y": On**l**y.

Then remove he who begins a cheer

> I think it refers to the letter "h": C**h**eer.

Next take away the end of a tunnel

> Tun**nel**

Then let us go to solve this puzzle

> Again, I believe this is a very literal clue: you need to "let go" of your previous findings, leaving you with: l, h, nel.

What you first took you must now take again

> Remove the "el" from n**el**.

With three you are left, but fret not dear friend

> Now we have three letters: l, h, n.

Fattest to front and thinnest to rear

> Line them up by width to height ratio: n, h, l.

Add in two "eyes" and all becomes clear

> N**i**h**i**l. It means zero in latin. It could also mean "nothing", so the "all becomes clear" part might be an intended pun.

Comment: "all becomes clear" -> love it

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this riddle is

> **"a number"** 
>  On the principle that it says the answer in the title and again in the body of the question.
>  "*Like the title says (I'm not very good with titles), you're looking for **a number** here.*"
> and
> "*As you can tell from the title, **I tend to be very literal with my words.***"